# Smart Card S/MIME with Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app, smartcard, smime

I have an Exchange 2013 environment that I'm trying to implement S/MIME with smart cards.  To the best of my knowledge, and the little help I have received on TechNet, I have configured my Exchange server correctly.  I have installed the S/MIME controls on a Windows computer, I am able to log into OWA with a smart card, but when I try to sign an email or tell OWA which certificate to choose for digital signatures, nothing happens.

Has anyone successfully signed or encrypted an email using a smart card with OWA 2013, or have any ideas about what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Is anything logged to the Windows Event logs when you try to choose a certificate?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay.  No events are logged and my card reader does indicate that the card was even accessed.

Comment: If you insert your the smart card to the reader, what are the certificates does your system detects? Does it also detect the certificate for mail encryption?

Comment: All of the certificates are detected just fine.  If I load up Outlook 2013 I can send Signed, Encrypted and Decrypt emails all day.  If I try OWA on the same computer it doesn't work.  Do you have this working in your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  First, the Signing cert was missing Email Protection EKU.  Second, the emails need to be sent as plain text.  I have yet to find the document that states the users emails must be sent as plain text for this to work in a browser, so if somebody comes across it, please enlighten me.